# JPA query take huge amount of time for basic select query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have created JPA entities class. But using basic query taking humongous amount of time for basic sql query having 100 records in database.

I have 4 tables. (Group/GroupA/GroupB/GroupC) having below structure.

```
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "publish_date")
    private LocalDate publishDate;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private GroupA groupA;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private GroupB groupB;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private GroupC groupC;
}

@Table(name = "groupA")
public class GroupA {   
    @Id
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Long groupID;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Group Group;

}

@Table(name = "groupB")
public class GroupB {    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Long groupID;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Group Group;    
}

@Table(name = "groupC")
public class GroupC {    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Long groupID;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Group Group;

}
```

**Repository class:**

```
@Repository
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Long> {    
    @Query("select r from Group r WHERE r.publishDate = ?1")
    List<Group> findAllGroupForDate(LocalDate businessDate);    
}
```

The above basic query is taking 1 minute 30 seconds for around 100 rows in Main Group table.

Please help if I am making anything wrong in entity class.

THanks.

Comment: Do you need groupA, groupB and groupC elements also in you select query?

Comment: Turn on SQL logging and look at the queries being generated to get an idea on what can be done to optimize. Something a simple as making certain parts of the graph lazy might drastically help - especially if they are not needed by the application. Just because you are getting 100 rows match; what matters is how many rows are in those tables - you may need indexes on the publish_date and the foreign keys in the various tables involved in the fetching required to build instances of Group. 100 groups could mean up to 300 queries into the groupA,GroupB and GroupC tables on the "id" FK column.

Comment: @Chris, that's true. For my main table there is 1 query, which triggers three more queries for every row fetched. (Ex - 30 rows in group table, means 90+1 = 91 queries in total)

Comment: @Chris , what should be the solution for this?

Comment: @Thinker please answer Amimul's question. What result do you want? Do you need GroupA, GroupB and GroupC as well, or just the "Group"?

Comment: there is no one solution for performance issues. If you are seeing 90 queries though, you are experiencing the well documented N+1 issue, which is commonly 'solved' by joining them to the main 1 query. Something like "select r from Group r fetch join r. groupA fetch join r. groupB fetch join r. groupC WHERE r.publishDate = ?1" would help greatly, assuming you really need A,B and C with every group instance. Making those relationships lazy and not touching them on the instance would help too, probably more so.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the Lazy loading concept.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Comment: not working. still huge time

Comment: When using Hibernate, LAZY doesn't work on the parent (non-owning) entity out of the box.